# jQuery greyScale is not greyscaling and displays wrong images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, wordpress, grayscale

I'm using [this jQuery greyscale plugin](https://github.com/Prydie/jQuery-GreyScale-Plugin). [Example page](http://www.pryde-design.co.uk/projects/jQGreyScale/example.html), [Developer page](http://www.pryde-design.co.uk/2011/08/greyscale-jquery-plugin/).

Now the effect works only in Internet Explorer. I have three images on that page. The first two aren't greyscaled - I can see them always in color (with/without hover effect). The third image is greyscaled, but if I hover the mouse on it I see the greyscaled image of the second image.

This is how I instantiate the greyScale function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        // fade in the grayscaled images to avoid visual jump
        jQuery("[class^='wp-image-'], [class*=' wp-image-']").hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
    // user window.load to ensure images have been loaded
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        jQuery("[class^='wp-image-'], [class*=' wp-image-']").greyScale({
            // call the plugin with non-defult fadeTime (default: 400ms)
            fadeTime: 500,
            reverse: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the output of the second image in Firebug:

```
<div class="gsWrapper" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
    <img width="80" height="80" alt="" src="http://www.adomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/picture2.jpg" title="Picture" class="size-full wp-image-317 alignnone" style="display: inline;">
</div>
```

This is the output of the third image in Firebug:

```
<div class="gsWrapper" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
    <img width="80" height="80" alt="" src="http://www.adomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/picture3.jpg" title="Picture 3" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-320" style="display: inline;">
    <canvas style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px;" width="80" height="80" class="gsCanvas"></canvas>
    <canvas style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px;" width="80" height="80" class="gsCanvas"></canvas>
    <canvas style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 1;" width="80" height="80" class="gsCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Firebug doesn't show me a 
In my opinion this feature worked, but now it seems borken. What has changed? How can I locate the error?

I tried to load the scripts in `functions.php` with `wp_enque_script` to avoid jQuery conflicts. Also I put my jQuery code below `wp_head()` in `header.php` and changed my calls here from `$` to `jQuery`. Currently I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 (tried it with 1.8.2 with the same effect). I also tried to deactivate all plugins, but still the same effect.

Now I saved the page within Internet Explorer and opened it in Firefox. The page then works. It seems it has to do with the rendering?

**Edit:**

So the plugin works with `canvas` in FF. Every image should have the a `canvas`image:

```
<div class="gsWrapper" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
    <img width="80" height="80" alt="" src="http://www.adomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/image4.jpg" title="image4" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1515" style="display: inline;">
    <canvas style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 1;" width="80" height="80" class="gsCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

In my case only the last image has a canvas field (here the last image has all canvas fields!). So the code is appended to the wrong elements. The plugin has the following JS-code:

```
this.each(function(index) {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="gsWrapper">');
    gsWrapper = $(this).parent();
    // ...
```

So first it wraps an element around it and then it is accessed again. Perhaps the error is in these lines together with `index`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found the error. The domain had an temporary URL. Now the site went online and got a new domain. The script made a proxy request and here it somehow appended to the wrong element.

Now I changed the links in the HTML to the new domain and now it works fine. Nevertheless the proxy request seems to fail and should be improved:

```
$.getImageData({
    url: $(this).attr('src'),
    success: $.proxy(function(image) {
        can = greyScale(image, image.width, image.height);
        if ($options.reverse) { can.appendTo(gsWrapper).css({"display" : "block", "opacity" : "0"}); }
        else { can.appendTo(gsWrapper).fadeIn($options.fadeTime); }
      }, gsWrapper),
    error: function(xhr, text_status){
      // silently fail on error
    }
});
```